# Selenium Test Execution in "Parallel" using 'TestNG'

Tags: selenium, testng

I am running the **Selenium** **Test** **cases** in parallel using **TestNG** in different browsers. (usage of: Selenium-Grid) 
I want to execute the same test case in different browser with different(variation of same) data.
For eg. a same data can not be used in case of 'registration' over different browsers. As once the member is registered on a website can not register again in the same.

Req: Registration test case in 3 browsers **IE,FF,Chrome** in parallel. I am using

```
@DataProvder(name="RegData",parallel=true) 
public Object[][] getRegData() { 
Object[][] data = {{"Max","Male","Italy"},{"James","Male","France"},{"Alex","Male","Spain"}}; 
return data; 
}
```

This data is utilized as Test Data. But what happens is each test case is executed 3 times. Each Test-case with each 'data' instance. so 3 Test Cases x 3 'data' entries = 9 executions. Each data instance should be utilized only once. Total executions should be only 3

Comment: can you try via DataProviders and Using Parallel Option of TestNG. As far as i know...TestMethod will be invoked as many times as my data has and since it's parallel...it will be executed with different data set....Not sure if it helps...

Comment: Tried "parallel" dataprovider as well as test but of no much help. 
Req: Registration test case in 3 browsers IE,FF,Chrome in parallel.I am using
@DataProvder(name="RegData",parallel=true)
public Object[][] getRegData(){
   Object[][] data = {{"Max","Male","Italy"},{"James","Male","France"},{"Alex","Male","Spain"}};
return data;
}
This data is utilized as Test Data. But what happens is each test case is executed 3 times. Each Test-case with each 'data' instance.
so 3 Test Cases x 3 'data' entries = 9 executions.
Each data instance should be utilized only once. Total executions should be only 3

Answer (score 0):

The intention of the dp is to do exactly that.  Run a set of steps with different data.
You are running the testcase in 3 browsers and with 3 data.  So each browwser would run with each of the 3 data.  That is expected.

If you want that one data should go to one browser then the browser too should be passed as part of the dataprovider.
So data1 with browser1, data2 with browser2 and data3 with browser 3 - this would ensure each browser runs with one data.

In your flow, it seems you are testing registration thrice.  The design seems to be incorrect from whatever you mention.

Comment: That's what I have said dataprovider is not solving my requirement. How should I proceed? I want to pass one data in each browser only once in parallel. Is it possible by dataprovider option or what wouldb e the alternative for it? –

Comment: how are you triggering on different browsers?

Comment: I have added different browser capabilities as parameters in 
testng.xml. As 3 browsers I am testing, I have created 3 <test>.
But I dont want to pass data through this testng.xml
It will be coming from some data provider like excel.