# Parallel execution of Test using @DataProvider

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, dataprovider, parallel-testing

I'm using testNg for `Selenium` automation using java, I'm using `@DataProvider` to get data from excel and pass as an argument to the test Script.

Suppose if I have 10 rows of data in `Excel`, my test case will execute 10 times sequentially, but now I want to run those 10 tests in parallel, all at the same time using threads.

Can this be done? If yes, can somebody provide me a sample example for the same?

Comment: Please check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138944/selenium-test-execution-in-parallel-using-testng?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can specify "parallel=true" in your dataprovider method which enables parallel execution.

Sample Code:Hope this helps.

```
@DataProvider(name="browserinfo",parallel=true)
    public static Object[][] browserinfo(){
        Object[][] testdata=new Object[][] {
            {Platform.WINDOWS,"firefox"},
            {Platform.LINUX,"chrome"},
            {Platform.MAC,"safari"}};

    return testdata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sauce lab for parallel execution, there you can execute in virtual machines at a time 30 Threads.

One more suggestion you can use selenium grid which will run parallel execution in different machines.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack and Sauce Labs both provide examples on parallel TestNG tests:

- [browserstack/testng-browserstack: Selenium examples for TestNG and BrowserStack Automate](https://github.com/browserstack/testng-browserstack)
- [saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Java-TestNG-Selenium](https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Java-TestNG-Selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the link.You will get an idea.
https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/parallel-execution-of-test-methods-in-testng